# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

Trying to install rails 3.2.7.
Still stuck with the problems of rvm etc.

```
gem install rails
```

fetches me following :-

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository

How can I get rails 3.2.7 up and working in my system?

Comment: What happens when you execute `where ruby`?

Comment: "The problems of rvm"?  Since you didn't mention rvm again(and you definitely want to be using it), perhaps you could elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rvm gem install rails`

I just did it and it worked for me.

If you don't have rvm, then:

1. If you don't have ruby:

Install RVM and ruby:

$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

or

Additionally with rails: 
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails

Comment: that'll install rails but not 3.2.7... I have done all this, but i want specifically rails 3.2.7...
pleas tell me the command for rails 3.2.7

Comment: Have you tried `gem install rails -v=3.2.7` ? Or if you want to install latest version of rails you can use `gem install rails -v ">=3.2.7"` It should work. [Reference](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html)

Answer (score 7):

`gem sources` should at least contain `https://rubygems.org`. If not

```
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org
```

should help.